# Razor generating ragged html does it require Html.Raw?

Tags: html, razor, html-helper, razor-2

Given a dynamic grid model generating html via razor similar to:

```
@{ int blockCounter = 0;}

@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    if (blockCounter++ % 3 == 0)
    {
    //ragged html open here, when needed
    }

    <div>..... </div>

    if (blockCounter % 3 == 0)
    {
    //ragged html close, when needed
    }

}
```

Is there any alternative to

```
if (blockCounter++ % 3 == 0)
{
@Html.Raw(@"<div class=""row"">")
}
```

If the following code is used:

```
if (blockCounter++ % 3 == 0)
{
    <div class="row">
}
```

This results in **Parser Error** Parser Error Message: The foreach block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

This parser error is false, as commenting out the ragged html or inserting it into a raw block removes the error. Is the raw block the only solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use @: to output text for single lines within a code block or the <text> tag for multiple lines

```
// single line
if (blockCounter++ % 3 == 0)
{
    @:<div class="row">
}

// multiline
if (blockCounter++ % 3 == 0)
{
    <text>
        <div class="row">
        <span>more output</span>
    </text>
}
```

Additional syntax references can be found here... http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-(c)